# How to design MongoDB data model to store Event Sourcing events

Tags: mongodb, database-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

If I create a single `table` (or `document` in `document databases`) per `aggregate type`,I can merge databases or shard them whenever I refactor the `write` side's `microservices`, and as the result the application becomes more scalable, and it also increases the speed of loading `events`.

Are there any side effects I should be aware of while I'm designing the `event store` like that?

**Edit:**

I'm currently using `MongoDb`.

What if I create a `collection` per `aggregate id` ? 
Or a `database` per `aggregate type`, and a `collection` per `aggregate id` ...?

Is that problematic in performance, ease of data administration, maintainability, or further scalability?

Comment: Are you talking about Table-Per-Aggregate-Type (every event a row in the table) or Document-Per-Aggregate-Instance (One document per instance, events as an array inside the document, single collection for all aggregates)?

Comment: Would the question be better formulated as "how do I design my MongoDB data model to store Event Sourcing events"?

Comment: @guillaume3:This kind of event data design, leads to non-linear event store (all aggregates aren't ordered in a single table , or document, or file ...) at the write side and I'm looking for the problems it can provide in different situations (specially MongoDb). For example maybe such a design is OK for Sql databases but not for MongoDb...

Comment: Carlos G:I added more information

Comment: @Mohsen OK in terms of what? Performance? Ease of data administration? Maintainability? Further scalability? If your problem is MongoDB specific, you should mention it in the question and add a tag. Also, the Q's title doesn't seem to convey the real issue here.

Comment: guillaume31:All of them. I will edit the title and question itself.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I create a single table (or document in document databases),I can merge databases or shard them whenever I refactor the write microservices, and as the result the application becomes more scalable.
>
> Are there any side effects I should be aware of while I'm designing the event store like that?

I haven't seen any authoritative discussion of that design.

There was a discussion in the event sourcing community about having a separate table for each *type* of aggregate.  You can find that discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dddcqrs/RK8wagtJZRg/discussion).  Executive summary: the more experienced practitioners seemed to be startled that anybody would do that on purpose.

One thing that you should keep in mind is that while events are real (they describe something of interest to the business), aggregates are artificial.  You are probably going to be unhappy if redesigning your aggregate boundaries requires that you move your events all over the place.

The following may be helpful

- https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore.Persistence.MongoDB
- http://www.slideshare.net/dbellettini/cqrs-and-event-sourcing-with-mongodb-and-php
- http://blingcode.blogspot.com/2010/12/cqrs-building-transactional-event-store.html

Comment: :Thank you. The answer isn't clear enough; would you please explain clearer? What do you mean by  `that` in the sentence : `I haven't seen any authoritative discussion of that design.`...? Thnks you.

Comment: I just clarified the question.